# When apply an attribute in class and method together, How to force use method attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, actionfilterattribute

I have an attribute to check authentication in controller actions. My attribute like this :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthenticationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private readonly bool checkAuthentication;
    public AuthenticationRequiredAttribute(bool checkAuthentication)
    {
        this.checkAuthentication = checkAuthentication;
    }

    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (checkAuthentication && !UserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); 
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{
                                        {"controller", "Account"},
                                        {"action", "Login"}
                                    });
        }
    }
}
```

If `checkAuthentication = false` no check authentication.
All actions in a controller should be check authentication except one action. I apply `[AuthenticationRequired(true)]` on controller and `[AuthenticationRequired(false)]` on specific action. but it not work and always check authentication. 
When apply `[AuthenticationRequired(true)]` on other actions and remove it from controller it work fine.

**How I can force use method attribute in this case?**

Comment: Could you give us the code where the attribute is being inspected?

Comment: @LuisFilipe I edit my question and add attribute code.

Comment: is it even possible what you want? The default Authorize Attribute does not support such a thing and have a different attribte: AllowAnonymous..see code here https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs and see SkipAuthorization function Maybe you can also apply this kind of solution in youre scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `OnAuthentication` and add validation of `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

```
bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                                 || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

        if (skipAuthorization)
        {
            return;
        }
```

After that just add `AllowAnonymous` attribute to methods that should skip authentication\authorization.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a controller level filter, then it applies to all actions and overrides any filters of the same name.

You can either just apply the filter to each action, or try using the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343929/3485021). This will let you specify what actions to exclude.